# Using Gatsby-image on array from markdown

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using Gatsby and have images that are referenced in each markdown file in an array. I would like to be able to use Gatsby-image to transform these images but cannot get it to work with the array.

I can get this to work when working with a single image from markdown

I have this query to get the data:

```
query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        id
        category
        title
        path
        prices
        salePercent
        images
      }
    }
  }
```

I have this coming from the markdown

`mainImage: './images/1.jpg'`

`images: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`

I can get gatsby-image to work fine with the mainImage but cannot get the query to work with the array.

I would like to be able to get gatsby-image to work with the array and transform each image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use YAML format in frontmatter like this:

```
images:
- image: "home-DSC_0035.jpeg"
  image_alt: "beautiful photo"
- image: "home-DSC_0045.jpg"
  image_alt: "This is better"
- image: "home-DSC_0043.jpg"
  image_alt: "This is much better"
```

You'll get array.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have actually solved this now. It was me being very stupid. I just needed to reference the actual image path and name in the array and it worked great. Thanks for your time.